# Are there any default arguments for procedures if they have only one?

Tags: scheme, lisp, racket

Could someone explain the following expression

```
> (+)
0
> (+ 1)
1
> (- 1)
-1
> (/ 1)
1
> (/ 2)
1/2
> (/ 3)
1/3
```

If there is a default argument of 1, why does `(+ 1)` return `1` while `(/ 2)` return `1/2` ?

Shouldn't `(+ 1)` return `2` ?

Answer (score 5):

For `+` and `*` the implicit default first argument is the identity element for the mathematical operations they represent, which are the addition and multiplication operations over various number fields.  For `+` this is `0` which is the identity element for the group of addition over numbers; for `*` this is `1` which is the identity element for multiplication over numbers.

So

- `(+)` is `(+ 0)` is `0`;
- `(+ 1)` is `(+ 0 1)` is `1`;
- `(*)` is `(* 1)` is `1`;
- `(* 2)` is `(* 1 2)` is `2`.

For `-` and `/` the implicit default arguments are the appropriate identities of the operations that these are the inverses of as well, although these functions require at least one argument, and their behaviour with more than one argument is not quite as simple.

So

- `(-)` is an error (I don't see why it should not be `0`);
- `(- 1)` is `(- 0 1)` is `-1`;
- `(- 1 2)` is *not* `(- 0 1 2)`;
- `(/)` is an error (I don't see why it should not be `1`);
- `(/ 2)` is `(/ 1 2)` is `1/2`;
- `(/ 3 2)` is *not* `(/ 1 3 2)`.

To be really precise, in the Scheme context, the default arguments are the *exact* numbers representing the identities I think.

Note that these default arguments are just chosen for mathematical convenience: this is not something inherent in the design of the language.  I could define a language where `(+)` was `"foo"`, although it would probably not be a very useful language.

Comment: The expansion `(/ 2)` to `(/ 1 2)` and the expansion `(- 2)`to `(/ 0 2)` are wrong conceptually.  This is not what it means.  The unary application of `/` and `-` yield the multiplicative resp. additive _inverses_ of ther argument.

Comment: Are those from the conclusion of  your test or the rule of scheme?

Comment: @Svante: It's the same.  If you define p(x,y) as a function corresponding one of the operations of the field, then define q(x,y) = p(x,i(y)) where i(x) is the inverse of x for any x (bar the zero the operation that has one).  Then define p(x) = p(e,x) where e is the identity, and correspondingly define q(x) = q(e,x).  So then q(x) = q(e,x) = p(e,i(x)) = i(x).

Comment: Perhaps “wrong” is too strong.  What I mean is: yes, it is the same, but building the inverse is a one-step process.  Going the route over division resp. subtraction from the identity element feels like a detour.

Comment: @Svante: certainly if I was being a mathematician I prefer the two-operation-and-inverse approach to things (so I agree with you). I'm not sure whether machines offer an inverse instruction (specifically a reciprocal one): if they don't then implementationally you need to do the division I suppose.

Comment: @MMMMMCCLXXVII: the *results* I'm giving are (unless I have made a mistake) what Scheme says, with the exception of `(-)` &c.  The intermediate steps are my own devising, and (see comment by Svante) there are several approaches to this.

Answer (score 3):

> If there are default argument 1, why (+ 1) return 1 ...

Look carefully. For `+`, the "default argument" is actually `0` (and not `1` as you claim):

```
> (+)
0
```

This is exactly what the [documentation](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=%2B#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._%2B%29%29) says about `+`:

> ... If no arguments are provided, the result is 0.

Then when you add `1` to `0`, you get `1`:

```
> (+ 1)
1
```

(Note: If you want to add `1` to a number, use [`add1`](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/generic-numbers.html?q=add1#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._add1%29%29)). e.g. `(add1 1)` -> `2`)

For a variadic procedure (i.e. a procedure that can take a variable number of arguments), the "default argument" depends on how the procedure was implemented. For example, if you define a variadic procedure using `(define (f . arglist) ...)`, the implicit default argument depends on how the body of the procedure makes use of `arglist`.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand the [reduce and fold](https://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/Reduction-of-Lists.html) operations.  `+` and `-` can be expressed as reductions, but in reductions you explicitly see the value for empty set of operands.

Comment: @WillNess what's the problem?  `Minus` operator is defined as 
`(define x '(1 2 3)) (display (fold-left - (car x) (cdr x)))`. Empty input list results in an error too.  I stated that both operators can be rewritten as reductions.  The OP can try to rewrite them alone and see the limit values, etc.